# Expanding a function

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Is it possible to expand a function
$$
f(x,y) = \dfrac{\sin (xy)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
$$
so it will be continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Now, the denominator should not be equal to $0$, so for the domain, there is a condition $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} > 0$. This condition prevents it from being continous there.

Comment: "continuous there" ... *where*? At the origin $\;(0,0)\;$ it cannot be as it is explicitly rejected, so where?

Comment: Continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: But if you have **the condition** $\;\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>0\iff (x,y)\neq (0,0)\;$ then it can *not* be defined on the origin, and it is continuous *everywhere else* ...

Comment: Yes I know. I want to expand the function, so it will be continuous on whole $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that
$$
|f(x,y)|=\left|\frac{\sin(xy)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\le \frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \quad \forall (x,y)\ne (0,0).
$$
Therefore $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=0$ and so you can define a continuous function by setting
$$
\tilde{f}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
f(x,y) &\mbox{ if } (x,y)\ne (0,0)\\
0 & \mbox{ if } (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $g_y(x) = \sin(xy)$ and $h_y(x)=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Near $x = 0$ one has :
$$g_y(x) \approx yx + \mathcal{O}(x^3),\quad h_y(x) \approx y + \mathcal{O}(x^2).$$
Thus :
$$f(0,0) = \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \left .\dfrac{g_y}{h_y}\right\rvert_{x = 0} = \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \left .\dfrac{yx}{y}\right\rvert_{x = 0} = 0.$$
So $f(x,y)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$ iff you accept the origin in the domain.